# Prerender es6 Errors with Angular 2/Typescript/Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, ecmascript-6, prerender

I'm trying to use prerender-node and a private prerender server to prerender an Angular2/Express app. If I try to target es5 in my tsconfig.json, the prerender server throws this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map

undefined:1521 in KeyRegistry
:1540
:7
```

If I try to target es6 (including `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts` in the `files` array), the prerender server throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'

http://localhost:3000/app.js:50 in eval
http://localhost:3000/app.js:50
http://localhost:3000/app.js:20 in __webpack_require__
http://localhost:3000/app.js:40
```

I'm guessing I need to include some sort of polyfill in order for this to work, but I don't have the first idea what to include or where to include it.

Here's my webpack config in case that helps:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var rootDir = path.resolve();

module.exports =
{
    target: 'node',
    entry: rootDir + "/dist/client/app/bootstrap.js",
    output: {
        path: rootDir + "/dist/client", publicPath: '/', filename: "app.js",
        pathinfo: true
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    resolve: {
        root: rootDir + "/dist/client/app",
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts/, loaders: ['ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And my client tsconfig in case that helps:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "../../dist/client",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "files": ["app/bootstrap.ts", "app/vendor.ts", "app/Window.ts", "tests/index.ts", "../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"]
}
```

## Update

If I change my webpack config to target `web` instead of `node`, and comment out `server.use(prerender.removeScriptTags());` in the prerender server, the request hits the prerender server every time and no errors are thrown, but nothing is prerendered, either. Seems closer than before, though, so I thought I'd update.

## Update

Prerender doesn't seem to execute any Angular code. If I set `window.prerenderReady = false` in a script tag in the head in my index.html, and then try to set it to true again when my root component is instantiated, the prerender server times out:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div id="main"> all the things </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit()
    {
        // Prerender never executes this code before it times out
        window.prerenderReady = true;
        console.info('Prerender Ready');
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like those javascript errors are preventing PhantomJS (the underlying rendering engine) to fail out and stop rendering the page. Did you include a polyfill for Map? `removeScriptTags` only removes the script tags after the page is done rendering so that shouldn't affect anything to do with rendering.

Comment: Targeting 'web' instead of 'node' in my webpack config sqashed the prerender es6 errors. The prerender server returns a 200, but no Angular code is executed.

Comment: Are there any other details I could provide that might help get an answer on this?

Comment: Can you send us an email at support@prerender.io with the URL you are using? That way we can test some pages against our prerender server.

Comment: This hasn't been deployed yet. Testing locally. I did manage to get it working. I outlined the steps in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working with the following changes:

Use `target: 'web'` in Webpack config.

Use `target: 'es5'` and add `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts` to files array in tsconfig.json. This prevents compile-time errors on es6 stuff.

Apparently, despite targeting web and es5, Webpack still leaves es6 styntax around that PhantomJs can't deal with. I don't love the idea of including babel in a Typescript project, but this is the only thing I've found that works: `require('babel-polyfill');` BEFORE any application code or vendor code that may use any es6 syntax.

Set `window.prerenderReady = false;` in the `head` of the document and then set it to `true` when you instantiate the root application component:

```
export class ApplicationComponent implements OnInit
{
    ngOnInit()
    {
        window.prerenderReady = true;
    }
}
```

NOTE: for the above to work in Typescript you'll need to make sure the property `prerenderReady` exists on type Window. E.g.:

```
interface Window
{
    prerenderReady:boolean;
}
```

On the server side, make sure you configure prerender-node BEFORE any routes are configured. E.g.:

```
export function routeConfig(app:express.Application):void
{
    // Prerender
    app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', CONFIG.prerenderServiceUrl));

    // Angular routes should return index.html
    app.route(CONFIG.angularRoutes)
        .get((req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) =>
        {
            return res.sendFile(`${app.get('appPath')}/client/index.html`);
        });
}
```

Hope this helps someone :)